# How to configure Auto update in MAUI application?

Tags: .net, maui, msix, maui-windows

Consider we have developed a MAUI application, for deployment of this MAUI application in multiple windows machine, we created a setup file / package following this link - https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder.md

Suppose we created a package with version 1.0.0 and got it installed in various machines. Now we want to release a new version of our application 1.0.1.

Is there any way using which Auto update of the application can happen during application start? We tried to use installer location concept from above link where we put the server's link and put the complete package on that link but during application start Auto update does not happen. Please guide us if there is any way for Auto update in MAUI.

This is what we have tried -->
https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/blob/main/docs/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder.md

We tried putting the package on server and gave that link as a installer location : e.g I have put the package on server on path - https://www.example.com/MAUI
and then opened the old version 1.0.0, the application did not auto update.

Also tried giving local path - D:/MAUI/{package files} but still auto update did not happen.

Comment: Well this feature is actually called ClickOnce but in .net MAUI is combined with the publish option. I suppose that you have selected the option to enable Automatic updates and the option to check for updates Every time the application runs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas Yes, I have selected option to enable Automatic updates and the option check for updates Every time the application runs. But whenever we run the application, Auto update does not work. So any idea on this ?

Comment: Are you sure that the newest version .1 can be installed correctly? If you uninstall version .0 and reinstall the latest version from the same url what will happened? The link must be the same all of the times.

Comment: @IsidorosMoulas During package creation there is a option for installer location, we are keeping the url same for each version. Point you are talking about manually installing from link I think it is of Clickonce concept. Is there any way for auto update in MAUI ?

Comment: The maui project on the windows is base on WinUI 3. So you can check [this discussion about the windows app auto update on the github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/7161).